# Receiving null when using LocalDao getData() with ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, realm

when im using getData method from my local database DAO via ViewModel and try to receive data in activity im getting nulls, but when i use exactly same function(getData) implemented inside activity it works properly. My data doesn't survive 1st approach somehow. Simplified code below.

FormDao

```
class FormDao(val realm: Realm) {

    fun findById(id: Int): LiveData<Form> {
        val liveData = MutableLiveData<Form>()
        val form = realm
            .where(Form::class.java)
            .equalTo("id", id)
            .findFirst()!!
        liveData.postValue(form)
        return liveData
    }

}
```

I made my FormDao extension of the realm object so anytime I have an instance of the realm object I can easily access the db queries in the FormDao class.

RealmDao.kt

```
fun Realm.formDao() : FormDao = FormDao(this)
```

ViewModel

```
open class NewFormViewModel(private val repository: FormRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val realm: Realm by lazy {
        Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    }

    fun getForm(): LiveData<Form> {
        return realm.formDao().findById(53)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        realm.close()
        super.onCleared()
    }
}
```

Its factory class

```
class NewFormViewModelFactory(private val repository: FormRepository) :
        ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory(){

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return NewFormViewModel(repository) as T
    }
}
```

Activity

```
class NewFormActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_form)

        val newFormViewModelFactory = NewFormViewModelFactory(repository = FormRepository())
        val newFormViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, newFormViewModelFactory).get(NewFormViewModel::class.java)


        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.addFormButton)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            var test1 = newFormViewModel.getForm()
            Log.v("LOGG", test1.value?.id.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

There is exisiting data with id = 53 in local DB so im expecting to get 53 as answer here, but its null for some reason. Local db work ok itself. Same thing happens when i try to get data from remote db with retrfoit. Thanks a million!

Comment: It seems like you wrote NewFormViewModel ViewModel incorrectly! Shouldn't ```getForm``` be more like the following?
 ```
    fun getForm(): LiveData<Form> {
        return formDao(realm).findById(53)
    }
```

Comment: I added an answer about it below so everyone can see. You can check it im doing it right with this approach.

Comment: I tried doing fun getForm(): LiveData<Form> {
        return FormDao(realm).findById(53) } as you recommended but didn't work either

Comment: I've seen you added an answer, does this means you have found a souation to your problem? If not, then please remove the answer and update the question with any updates that you might have for everyone to better understand the question. :)

Comment: Already done. Won't happen again :)

Comment: Can you show the working example from the activity? It will also be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found out what was the problem with my DAO. Im not used to work with LiveData so i made little mess with binding my custom class to LiveData.

```
fun findById(id: Int): LiveData<Form> {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<Form>()
    val form = realm
        .where(Form::class.java)
        .equalTo("id", id)
        .findFirst()!!
    liveData.value = form  <--- was liveData.pastValue(form)
    return liveData
}
```

Now DAO works fine. But as i said earlier i had problem with my Retrofit call aswell (that's what made me think it's about passing data between view and viewmodel etc), but i should probably make different question about that.